# When Silverlight app (xap) is loaded in browser for the first time, it initializes for more than 5 sec, why?

Tags: macos, silverlight, browser

On Mac when I load a page with Silverlight object, it takes 5 or more (sometimes 10+) seconds for the object to initialize. On consequent page reloads it initializes instantly (as one would expect). It is not about browser cache, since even if I clean the cache completely before the page reload, Silverlight object still initializes instantly. I do not observe anything such on Windows machines, it happens only on Mac. Object itself is not that big (~63kb). Although I should note that when I compile it without image manipulation classes ([FJCore](https://code.google.com/p/fjcore/) and [PngEncoder](http://catcode.com/pngencoder/index.html)) (size drops to ~17kb) it starts to load and initialize instantly. Not sure how to troubleshoot this.

Any ideas?

Comment: I had similar issue with Safari, as you know silverlight plugin implemented for different browsers. Do you use Safari or another ? You may compare Safari ,Firefox and others..

Comment: I started experiencing the same issue when I included the DotNetZip and ServiceStack.Text packages in my project.